# combinatorics: number of options to set a (a,b) ordered pair under terms

Tags: combinatorics, ordered-fields

We have to find the number of options for setting pair $(a,b)$ under the terms:
$a ⊆ b ⊆\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$
Means, they are both subsets of $\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$ and $a⊆ b$.

I was thinking to handle the $b$ coordinate first and by that, to handle the $a$ coordinate.
But, what are the number of options for $b$?

tahnx.

Comment: The number of options for $b$ is $2^n,$ the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}.$

Comment: ordered-fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, considering each element $1 \le m \le n$, we have
($m \not\in B$) or ($m \in B$ but $m \not\in A$) or ($m \in A$), hence there're three choice for each element.

So the answer is $3^n$.

Your thought is also available. It's algebraic: Let $U = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{B \subseteq U} \sum_{A \subseteq B} 1
&= \sum_{B \subseteq U} 2^{|B|} \\
&= \sum_{k} \sum_{\scriptstyle B \subseteq U \atop \scriptstyle |B| = k} 2^k \\
&= \sum_{k} \binom n k 2^k \\
&= (2+1)^n \\
&= 3^n
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The number of options for your pairs $(a,b)$ should be $\Sigma_{k=0}^n 2^k\binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

Each element is either in a and b, in b but not in a, or non of both.
edit: did'nt see the first part of Frank's answer. It's perfect.